# cleaning the whole screen

Tags: python, pygame, screen

```
import pygame
from pygame.constants import *

pygame.init()                                       # inicializa el display

ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))       # variable de la superficie de la ventana
pygame.display.set_caption("prueba")                # titulo de ventana

funcionando = True                                  # variable del booleano del mainloop

unRect = (50, 50, 100, 100)                         # variable de posicion de rectangulo
colorRect = (0, 255, 0)                             # variable de color de retangulo
colorTitulo = (0, 0, 0)
color2= (30,120,180)
aA = True
colorFTitulo = (30, 30, 180)
textoTitulo = "BIENVENIDO A BATTLESHIPS"
texto1 = "Pulse cualquier tecla para jugar"

my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier", 16)        # Instantiate 16 point Courier font to draw text.

ventana.fill(colorTitulo)



while funcionando:                                  # mainloop del juego

    for event in pygame.event.get():                # checkea todos los eventos en cola

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:               # checkea si hay un .QUIT entre los eventos
            funcionando = False                     # si lo hay funcionando cambia a False, el juego se cierra

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:    # checkea si hay un evento de tipo click en cola
            posClick = event.dict["pos"]            # recoge las coordenadas en una variable
            print(posClick)                         # imprime la posicion en la variable

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            ventana.fill(color2)

    titulo = my_font.render(textoTitulo, aA, colorFTitulo)
    txt1 = my_font.render(texto1, aA, colorFTitulo)
    ventana.blit(titulo, (180, 50))
    ventana.blit(txt1, (180, 370))

    ventana.fill(colorRect, unRect)                 # cada vez que se actualiza la ventana, pinta un rectangulo

    pygame.display.flip()                           # actualiza toda la ventana
```

What should I do so my script after press key, cleans everything in the screen? I've already managed to change the background color but now I want to clear also the text and the rect.

Any comment about how script is written is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your problem is that you are clearing the screen(refilling the background), BUT you are doing it before you draw the rectangles.

So everytime you hit a key, its only the background that gets cleared with color2, like you said.

I'm not sure what you want your game to do or how you want your code structured so I wont recommend moving the conditional to after the statement where you draw the rectangle, which would work and would be the simple solution.

What you could do instead is just set  a flag when they hit a key and check for the flag after the part where you draw the rectangle/text.

so:

```
...
...

if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        ventana.fill(color2)
        clearScreen=True   #<- set your flag

titulo = my_font.render(textoTitulo, aA, colorFTitulo)
txt1 = my_font.render(texto1, aA, colorFTitulo)
ventana.blit(titulo, (180, 50))
ventana.blit(txt1, (180, 370))

ventana.fill(colorRect, unRect)                 # cada vez que se actualiza la ventana, pinta un rectangulo

if clearScreen:
     ventana.fill(color2)
```

Again, alternatively, you could just move the conditional(or all of the conditionals) to after the part where you draw the additional elements.

Depends on what you plan on doing with the code.

P.S. os.system('clear') clears text on a TERMINAL screen, NOT the screen you are making with pygame.

Comment: wow really thanks i will try it. what i have pllaned is something like this: after run the scrip the window pops out and it first contain the title and the "press any key" phrase. After that the game should clean the window and all its content and draw a NxN board of circles. Thats my first objective for now. Im trying to write a def to draw the circs but i think it isnt too much good...

Comment: just hang in there, read the docs like they're the bible. Itt'l seem second nature soon, if you work hard, i promise.                        p.s. If my answer works for you, don't forget to upvote/accept (I could use the rep lol :D)

Comment: Another thing that will help you learn.... Once you get your code working completely, make and account on Code Review and put your code up there.... They will tear you a new one, but also teach you a lot

Comment: hey what docs are you talking about? i totally wanna read them!

Comment: https://docs.python.org  <- If your on windows, use the ones that came with python, otherwise, just make sure you're looking at the right version.

Comment: ^these are the docs^ A.K.A. "the manuals", google this phrase: RTFM

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the screen using
import os
os.system('cls') #on windows

and 
os.system('clear') #on linux and mac

Comment: just tried it, dont know if doing the right way, after the "if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            ventana.fill(color2)" os.system("cls") and it doesnt do anything. I have imported os

Comment: try to use os.system('cls') BEFORE ventana.fill(color2)